# How can I reorder row labels in the r package gt?

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats, gt

I am trying to reorder the [row labels](https://gt.rstudio.com/) in a `gt` table but, for some reason, it seems like the `forcats` function I'm using is being ignored by `gt`. Here's a reproducible example to illustrate what I mean:

(1) Here's what the exibble dataset (which comes with `gt`) looks like as a table using only the variables `group`, `char` and `currency`:

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

exibble %>% 
  select(group, char, currency) %>% 
  gt(groupname_col = 'group',
     rowname_col = 'char')
```

Photo of the resulting table:

[image]

(2) Let's say I want to be able to reorder the row labels so that `char` is ordered from largest to smallest fruit within each group. It should end up looking like this:

Photo of the ideal table:

[image]

(3) So I releveled `char` and expected the row labels in the table to be displayed in this new order:

```
exibble %>% 
  mutate(charOrdered = fct_relevel(char, c('durian', 'coconut', 'banana', 'apricot', 'honeydew', 'grapefruit', 'fig'))) %>% 
  select(group, charOrdered, currency) %>% 
  gt(groupname_col = 'group', 
     rowname_col = 'charOrdered')
```

However, it's as if `gt` has ignored the `forcats` function and kept the order of the new variable, `charOrdered`, alphabetical. Any idea why this is happening and how I can reorder row labels?

Photo of the resulting table (which is identical to the first table):

[image]

I'm using `R` 4.0.2, `dplyr` 1.0.2, `forcats` 0.5.0 and `gt` 0.2.2 on macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

I'm new to R and stack overflow, so any constructive feedback on how to better phrase questions is welcome and would be appreciated. Thank you!

---

In case you were wondering, I created the ideal table in (2) by creating vectors. However, this approach is not ideal as it is inefficient and prone to errors.

```
exibble %>% 
  mutate(fruit = c('durian', 'coconut', 'banana', 'apricot', 'honeydew', 'grapefruit', 'fig', NA)) %>% 
  mutate(currency = c('65100.000', '1.390', '17.950', '49.950', '0.440', NA, '13.255', '1325.810')) %>% 
  select(group, fruit, currency) %>% 
  gt(groupname_col = 'group', rowname_col = 'fruit')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `arrange` by `charOrdered`:

```
exibble %>% 
  mutate(charOrdered = fct_relevel(char, c('durian', 'coconut', 'banana', 'apricot', 'honeydew', 'grapefruit', 'fig'))) %>% 

  arrange(charOrdered) %>%

  select(group, charOrdered, currency) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  gt(groupname_col = 'group', 
     rowname_col = 'charOrdered')
```

[image]